# How to load new FXML as a popup box in javaFX

Tags: javafx

I am new in JavaFX, I fetched database value into table view form after that when I click on table row then I want to load another FXML page and load the database value into textfield.

[image]

Comment: These value should be load into textfield.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Loading the other fxml? Passing the data? Handling the row click?

Comment: Suppose when i double click on selected then new window will be open with all data from database should be load into textfield.

Comment: That's just the info from the question. Since this problem is 3 seperate problems, a request for code without a attempt to come up with an own solution or simply not written well this question is too broad

Comment: BTW: did you just ask the same question again, this time with more info instead of simply [edit]ing your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170481/how-to-load-database-value-in-textfield-from-selected-id-from-tableview

Comment: I am facing error in code so i just post the code.

Comment: Fabian can you go through the code and short out the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49170481/revisions   you can go through from here.

Comment: _you can go through from here_ - no, it's your job to post a coherent question once, complete with mcve if you struggle with an exception or something that's not working as you expect it to work. Without, you'll most probably don't get an answer and your question will be closed because it's not answerable

Answer (score -2):

To load another FXML file and show it in a new opened window (Main.class.getResource(...) has to be adjusted):

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("your.fxml")));
stage.setTitle("...");
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Comment: There is no overloaded version of `load` that takes a single `String` (also there's a syntax error in that line). Furthermore how do you know this is the op's problem? When I read the question I can identify 3 different independent issues immediately. Only one of them is addressed in your answer. How do you know it's the correct one?

Comment: The title is "How to load new FXML as a popup box in javaFX". That is what I answered.